# listview with simpleadapter not refreshing after adding new data to sqlite database

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, refresh, simpleadapter

I have a problem with my listview that when I add a task to my database, I need to update my listview with this new added task....

I'm new to android and Eclipse...

Here is my code for Main (that shows the `ListView`)

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    Button newCat;
    TextView todaytaskId;
    ResultDatabase controller5 = new ResultDatabase(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        newCat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewCat);
        newCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        CategoryList.class);

                startActivity(nextScreen);
            }
        });

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> todaytaskList = controller5
                .getTodayTasks();

        if (todaytaskList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    todaytaskId = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.todaytaskId);
                    String valtaskId = todaytaskId.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            DelayTask.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("todaytaskId", valtaskId);
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, todaytaskList,
                    R.layout.view_today_task, new String[] { "taskId",
                            "taskName", "taskTime" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.todaytaskId, R.id.todaytasktv,
                            R.id.todaytasktimetv});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


}
```

Here's my code to select tasks from ResultDatabase class

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getTodayTasks() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tasks where taskDate = date('now') AND taskDone = 'No'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("taskId", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("taskName", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("taskTime", cursor.getString(3));
            // map.put("taskDate", cursor.getString(4));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordList;

}
```

Comment: Why you commented NotifyDataSetChanged();? Try to call adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() after you call your update task

Comment: I think NotifyDataSetChanged(); is only used with ArrayAdapter

Comment: When I use listadapter with NotifyDataSetChanged(), I recieve errors that there are no method with this name used with the list adapter

Comment: Declare the adapter as an istance of SimpleAdapter, not ListAdapter. And then you call on your list todaytaskList.setAdapter(adapter).

Comment: Can you explain what kind of error? Runtime, Compile time? It's not possible that you can't call this method, as you can see it is present for SimpleAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html .

Comment: I tried with your way but I recieve error with:The method setAdapter(SimpleAdapter) is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: When I run the application I can see only tasks that I inserted them in sql statements from beggining and can't see the new tasks I'm inserting to the database... There is no Log errors appearing but the listview seems not updated

Comment: I'm sorry you have to call it on the listview, in your case lv, I suppose.

Comment: I will try lv.setAdapter(adapter)  now

Comment: I had no luck, I updated my code in case what I've added causes problems to the saving of data.... I'm not sure

Comment: I've updated my code. do you have any comments that will lead to fixing my problem?

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the data set that is connected on the adapter you must call **notifyDataSetChanged** to notify the adapter to update the views with the new data. You must also call requery on the Cursor to update the cursor with new data. To clarify you should call requery before notifyDataSetChanged.

Check sample code below

```
 public class WeatherAppActivity extends ListActivity {

 Button buton;
 ItemsAdapter lista;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

List<String> initialList = new ArrayList<String>();
initialList.add("Bucuresti");
initialList.add("Sibiu");

lista=new ItemsAdapter(this, initialList);
buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
buton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         lista.add(""+System.currentTimeMillis()); // e chiar getText()
         lista.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});

setListAdapter(lista);

}

 class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.lista, list);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View row, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final String item = getItem(position);

    ItemWrapper wrapper = null;
    if (row == null) {
        row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista, parent, false);
        wrapper = new ItemWrapper(row);

        row.setTag(wrapper);
    } else {
        wrapper = (ItemWrapper) row.getTag();
    }
    wrapper.refreshData(item);

    return row;
}

class ItemWrapper {

    TextView text;

    public ItemWrapper(View row) {
        text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementLista);
    }

    public void refreshData(String item) {
        text.setText(item);
    }

}
}    

}
```